# How to get a property from an object if property is integer?

Tags: xml, properties, integer

I use an *Microsoft translator* for translating simple texts. 
For example:

```
$key = "secret_key";
$translator = new MicrosoftTranslator($key);
$translator->translate("en", "cs", "sun");
$text = $translator->response->translation;
```

Get this response (in variable $text):

```
"<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">slunce</string>"
```

Now need only simple text in xml string format, just we can use

> simplexml_load_string

```
$string = simplexml_load_string($text);
```

Watch in Firebug and get (in object $string):

```
Object { 0 = "slunce" }

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => slunce
)
```

How can we access to this ($string)? $string->0 is **not allowed**.

Answer (score 0):

Solve, just convert to an array:

```
$string = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($text)), 1);
print_r($string);
```